# Why can't I disable .htaccess in Apache?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, mod-python

This is the opposite problem from most about which I have read. I am running Ubuntu 8.04 on an Amazon instance with Apache 2.2.8 and I can't figure out why setting AllowOverride to None for root doesn't stop my .htaccess file from being included.

I have a sub-directory with hello.py in it and an .htaccess file. When I browse to the file, it works fine with modpython serving the file. If I put some garbage in .htaccess I get a server error, so I know the .htaccess file is being used. Also if I delete the .htaccess file, hello.py is no longer server by modpython - instead the browser tries to open it.

In one of my sites-available (linked in sites-enabled), I have "AllowOverride None" for the root directory. I thought that this would prevent .htaccess from being included from root and all its sub-directories which should cause hello.py to not be served by mod_python. However, it continues to be served fine and I can test that .htaccess is still being included because when I modify it, I see the results in my browser.

Maybe there is something I am not understanding about my file in sites-enabled. This is the file I am using:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080 
<VirtualHost *:8080>
<Directory />
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: While AllowOverride None should stop it from reading .htaccess files, I note that your configuration contains nothing regarding mod_python (i.e., AddHandler mod_python .py).  What's in the .htaccess file?

Comment: .htaccess:
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mptest
PythonDebug On

and in mptest.py:
from mod_python import apache

def handler(req):
    req.log_error('handler')
    req.content_type = 'text/plain'
    req.send_http_header()
    req.write("Hello World!")
    return apache.OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the file is not served via mod_python when you delete .htaccess is because the setup for mod_python is located in it.  If you move that stuff to your sites-available file, you can delete .htaccess, turn a blind eye to the problem, and call it a day.

If that doesn't satisfy you, then as to why .htacess is being read at all, I can't say.   You are correct that AllowOverride None *should* prevent the file from ever being read.  Have you considered the possibility that you screwed something up when adding the virtual site?  Try throwing some garbage into the config and see if it complains, just to be sure it's being read at all.

Comment: I think you are right that the problem is with my virtual host. If I move the Directory tags containing AllowOverride outside of my VirtualHost tags then it works as expected - .htaccess is not included. Thanks for suggesting this.

Answer (score 2):

[`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is only allowed in `<Directory>`-sections, so you've done everything right.

One problem you could have is that other (sub-)`<Directory>`-sections set `AllowOverride` to something different than `None`. That will override the setting for these subdirectories.
I use

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and in `/var/www` (my docroot) I can use `.htaccess`es.

The reason why `mod_python` does not work anymore if you delete your `.htaccess` is that `mod_python` setup is usually in `.htaccess` files.

If you need more information, please send us your configuration.

PS: In fact the docuementation linked above says that you should **never** set `AllowOverride` to something not `None` in `<Directory />`.